# dplyr Rename column using another column name as reference

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
df <- tibble(material = c(1:10)
       ,x2 = c(letters[1:10]))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   material x2   
      <int> <chr>
 1        1 a    
 2        2 b    
 3        3 c    
 4        4 d    
 5        5 e    
 6        6 f    
 7        7 g    
 8        8 h    
 9        9 i    
10       10 j


colnames(df)[2] <- paste0('text_',colnames(df)[1])                     
colnames(df)[1] <- paste0('key_',colnames(df)[1])

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   key_material text_material
          <int> <chr>        
 1            1 a            
 2            2 b            
 3            3 c            
 4            4 d            
 5            5 e            
 6            6 f            
 7            7 g            
 8            8 h            
 9            9 i            
10           10 j
```

I'm trying to rename the second column (x2) based on the initial first column name (material)
First column will be renamed 'key_material' and second column will be renamed 'text_material'.

I want to turn the above steps into `%>%` flow.

Below my attempt

```
df %>% rename( paste0('text_', colnames(.)[1]) = 2
                     ,paste0('key_', colnames(.)[1]) = 1)
```

Although it seems that it wouldn't evaluate the expression.

Thanks!

Comment: this `df  %>% set_names(c("key_material", "text_material"))`?  Why so complicated?

Comment: I have multiple datasets, each one has different name on the first column. So it's important to be able to abstract away the first column name for automation purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rename_all` if you have only 2 columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename_all(~paste(c('key', 'text'), .[1], sep = "_"))

# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   key_material text_material
#          <int> <chr>        
# 1            1 a            
# 2            2 b            
# 3            3 c            
# 4            4 d            
# 5            5 e            
# 6            6 f            
# 7            7 g            
# 8            8 h            
# 9            9 i            
#10           10 j
```

Or `rename_at` if you have more columns but want to rename only first 2.

```
df %>% rename_at(1:2, ~paste(c('key', 'text'), .[1], sep = "_"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, and awesome assumption at the end as well. I do have more than 2 columns :)

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
df  %>% set_names(paste0(c("key_","text_"), names(.)[1]))
```

when more than two columns you can do

```
df %>% set_names(c(paste0(c("key_","text_"), names(.)[1]), names(.)[-1:-2]))
```